# Virtual Machine to run 32-bit Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-7, virtual-machine

I'm trying to run an old game, and oddly the expansion packs to the game only install on 32-bit Windows. I have 64-bit Windows 7, and it won't even let me attempt to install them. If I install a 32-bit Windows operating system on a virtual machine (e.g. XP), should this solve the problem?

Alternatively, is there any way I can trick the installer on the DVD into believing it is on a 32-bit system? I've tried running the game under compatibility mode for XP SP3.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This belongs on SuperUser...

Comment: Which old game?  gog.com (Good Old Games)  may (or may not) have a patched up version of the game.

Comment: Did you try XP compatibility mode in Win 7 64 bit?  Is your DirectPlay turned ON?   Control Panel->Programs and Features->Turn on or off windows features.  Look for DirectPlay buried in a sub menu.

Comment: Almost any VM will do. And your second question (don't ask two questions!) if off topic here. Voting to close as too broad.

Comment: This is a how-to question, not a software recommendation question, so I'm migrating it. Which VM to use could be a software recommendation question, but we'd need far more information to offer any useful information. What makes the game not work on a 64-bit Windows? Could you install it under a 32-bit emulation/VM and run it on the original? If you have to run it in a VM, how graphically intensive is it? Saying what game it is would help.

Comment: Which VM software did you try? All major players support using 32-bit guests on a 64-bit host OS.

Comment: You need to modify the compatibility of the setup.exe (or whatever its called).  Therefore, you need to copy the whole CD/DVD to the hard drive so windows can write to the folder.  Set the actual setup.exe to XP compatibility.  Sometime the setup.exe just launches a second EXE and you need to adjust the compatibility on that one also.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle Virtual Box will allow 32 or 64 bit OS to be emulated.

Answer (score 0):

[Windows XP Mode](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/install-and-use-windows-xp-mode-in-windows-7) could be helpful in this case.

it is:

> a virtual operating system and as a way to open programs within Windows 7. It runs in a separate window on the Windows 7 desktop, much like a program, except it's a fully-functional, fully-licensed version of Windows XP. In Windows XP Mode, you can access your physical computer's CD/DVD drive, install programs, save files

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend you to waste your time installing that game in a virtual machine or in a 'windows xp mode' one because the performance is going to be very bad compared with a 'host' installation.You won't be happy.

A separate clean "windows xp" installation is the best solution, but perhaps it's not an option for you, if you've a laptop.

I don't recommend a dual boot with Windows 7 and Windows XP also, because it's very tricky to isolate one operating system from the other. This may cause severe problems.

I've prepared a separate hard disk with "windows xp" and all the ancient games with problems. When I want to play them, I disconnect the power of the windows 7 disk/s from the main board and connect the power for the "windows xp" disk. This could be an ardous work in your system. I've got some power extenders and it's very easy and comfortable ;-)